# What happens if the same lock is used to enter different critical sections

Tags: c++, multithreading, operating-system, locking

I have 2 critical sections in my code . Can I use the same lock to enter different critical sections ? I'm not understanding what can go wrong with this code .

```
void func1(int y, int z)
{
   writeLock.lock()
     x = y; // critical section 1
   writeLock.unlock()
   ...
   while(1)
   {
      writeLock.lock()
        myVar = z; // critical section 2

      writeLock.unlock()
      if (z == 100)
        break;
   }
}
```

I don't want to do the assignment to of `x = y` inside the loop so I used the same lock in both places . Is it okay to do that ?

Comment: It doesn't seem immediately unreasonable. Though I'd suggest replacing the bare `lock/unlock` calls with a `lock_guard`. Let the compiler figure out all the ways a critical section can be exited instead of eyeballing it yourself.

Comment: Yes you can, but is it what you want to do? If both critical sections manipulate the same resources, using the same lock makes sense. If they manipulate different resources it still might make sense, but we'd need more information to make that call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `x` and `myvar` are totally disjoint, then you should not use the same mutex for these two critical sections, but one for each instead.

Doing so, if one threads is in the `x` critical section, then no other thread can enter the same critical section, but this other thread can enter the `myvar` critical section (and conversely).

In your solution, touching `x` prevents any other thread from touching `myvar` at the same time, which does not seem to be justified.

« is it OK? » yes, it is not *wrong* per se, but it is suboptimal since it artificially serialises different portions of code that could be executed concurrently.